# No being able to comment on profiles? (Steam)

Tags: steam

So I just logged onto steam and wanted to comment on my friends profile but when I click comment it doesn't appear? My steam is up to date, is this just a bug and is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried restarting Steam? It sometimes bugs out and does strange things like this.

Comment: Yes I restarted multiple times, nothing happened

Answer (score 2):

Random glitch. Tell your frined to go to his steam profile settings>privacy settings>''who can comment on my profile'' and reset it to public. Or switch it to something else and back at public again.

Answer (score -2):

In your profile settings you can choose to disable comments on your profile. Your friend must change it to Friends Only or Public. I would give a screenshot but Steam is down for me at the moment.

Comment: Uh. From what I can understand, the asker is able to comment on their friend's profile, it's just that the Post Comment button doesn't work.